# Setting value of field in all selected rows of table using ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, field-calculator

I have an attribute table in ArcGIS 10 (it's large - around 300,000 elements). I've selected some rows of the table using 'Select by attributes' and I want to set the value of a field for all of those rows.

How should I go about doing this? I'm hoping there will be a nice, easy, GUI-based way - as I'm teaching someone with very little GIS experience.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

How about opening the attribute table, change to the selected records then right-click on the field you want to change.  Choose Calculate Field and type the value you want all of the selected features to have.

Comment: For fields that are string/text make sure you surround your text with "", e.g. "string" within field calculator.

Comment: Ahh of course - I didn't quite think laterally enough... Cheers guys.