# Editing tables using SQL in ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, field-calculator, sql

We've recently started working with ArcMap, having used MapInfo previously. I've created a shapefile in ArcCatalog and want to update some columns using SQL. In MapInfo I'd write the following command in the MapBasic window.

```
UPDATE Clearance SET GTID = "GT" & FID
```

I can't find where to do this in ArcMap - any pointers?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the field calculator. An answer to another question explains how to do this:  [Setting value of field in all selected rows of table using ArcGIS Desktop?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/9493/how-to-set-the-value-of-a-field-in-all-selected-rows-of-a-table-using-arcgis-10/9494#9494)

There are also examples in the help:  http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Calculate_Field_examples/005s0000002m000000/

You could also use the [calculate field tool](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Using_the_Calculate_Field_tool/005s00000029000000/).